# Change button depending on like status

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am attempting to add a post liking system to my website. I already have the functionality to like and unlike posts, however I can't get the button value to change in the template.

models.py
class Post(models.Model):

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
summary = models.TextField(max_length=600)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
is_liked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
def likepost(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        if post.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            post.is_liked = True
            post.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            post.is_liked = False
            post.likes.add(user)
        return redirect('home')
```

home.html

```
{% if post.is_liked == True %}
                      <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('like__post').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Like {{ post.total_likes }}</button></a>
              {% else %}
                    <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('like__post').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Unlike {{ post.total_likes }} </button></a>
              {% endif %}

        <form id="like__post" method="POST" action="{% url 'likepost' post.id %}">
                {% csrf_token%}
                <input type="hidden">
              </form>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be saving the `post` variable after you change the value of `is_liked`.

Comment: My mistake, thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh that's my bad. Thanks for spotting that, the functionality is all perfect.